# SQL for retrieving tuples of not related records

Tags: sql, select, cross-join

Imagine a database like this:

[image: test database]

And looking for all the students - teachers sets that don't share any courses. Result should be a `(Student.Name - Teacher.Name)` tuple.

This idea is near the solution but not exactly what wanted.

```
--- The students that go to some courses 
SELECT S.FIRSTNAME, S.LASTNAME
FROM STUDENTS S
JOIN STU_COU SC ON S.STUDENTID = SC.STUDENTS_STUDENTID

UNION ALL

--- teachers not in attended courses 
SELECT T.FIRSTNAME, T.LASTNAME
FROM TEA_COU TC
JOIN TEACHERS T ON T.TEACHERID = TC.TEACHERS_TEACHERID
WHERE TC.COURSES_COURSEID NOT IN (
  SELECT C.COURSEID
  FROM STUDENTS S
  JOIN STU_COU SC ON S.STUDENTID = SC.STUDENTS_STUDENTID
  JOIN COURSES C ON C.COURSEID = SC.COURSES_COURSEID
);
```

Test data like:

- TEACHER A teaches CS and MATH courses;
- STUDENT A goes to CS course;
- STUDENT B goes to LITERATURE and SPORTS courses;

Result would be

```
STUDENT B - TEACHER A
```

Looking for universal solution that's why no particular database stated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could start with a cross join and then remove any pair that has a relationship:

```
SELECT     s.firstname, s.lastname, t.firstname, t.lastname
FROM       students s
CROSS JOIN teachers t
WHERE      NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
                       FROM   stu_cou sc
                       JOIN   tea_cou tc ON sc.courses_courseid = 
                                            tc.courses_courseid
                       WHERE  sc.students_studentid = s.studentid AND
                              tc.teachers_teacherid = t.teacherid)
```

Answer (score 3):

In Oracle you can use `minus`, or SQL Server or PostgreSQL's `except` set operator: (functionally equivalent)

```
select s.firstname as stud_fname,
       s.lastname  as stud_lname,
       t.firstname as teac_fname,
       t.lastname  as teac_lname
  from students s
 cross join teachers t
minus
select s.firstname,
       s.lastname,
       t.firstname,
       t.lastname
  from students s
  join stu_cou sc
    on s.studentid = sc.students_studentid
  join courses c
    on sc.courses_courseid
  join tea_cou tc
    on c.courseid = tc.courses_courseid
  join teachers t
    on tc.teachers_teacherid = t.teacherid
```

Comment: Note that in Postgres and MS SQL Server this operator is called `except`. Also note that MySQL doesn't have such an operator, unfortunately.

Comment: But neat solution nontheless.

Comment: As Mureinik pointed out: `MINUS` is Oracle specific. In the SQL standard it's named `except`

Comment: Forgot that the name is different (although it is functionally equivalent), just corrected for clarification

Answer (score 1):

This is similar to @Mureinik's solution, but it avoids the `CROSS JOIN` :

```
SELECT     s.firstname, s.lastname, t.firstname, t.lastname
FROM       students s
JOIN teachers t ON NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT *
    FROM   stu_cou
    JOIN   tea_cou tc ON sc.courses_courseid = tc.courses_courseid
    WHERE  sc.students_studentid = s.studentid
    AND tc.teachers_teacherid = t.teacherid
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution very similar to @Brian DeMilia, that works for MySQL:

```
SELECT
    s.firstname ,
    s.lastname ,
    t.firstname ,
    t.lastname  
from
    students s   
cross join
    teachers t  
where
    (
        s.firstname ,  s.lastname ,  t.firstname ,  t.lastname 
    ) NOT IN  (
        select
            s.firstname,
            s.lastname ,
            t.firstname,
            t.lastname  
        from
            students s  
        inner join stu_cou sc  
                on s.studentid = sc.students_studentid  
        inner join courses c  
                on sc.courses_courseid = c.courseid  
        inner join tea_cou tc  
                on c.courseid = tc.courses_courseid  
        inner join teachers t  
                on tc.teachers_teacherid = t.teacherid 
        );
```